# jquery find issue with counting children elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In the following code the div:first class name is create.so the code actually appends one more div to id `accordion` but when i do a console.log() to find the number of `.create` elements it always prints 1 what am i doing wrong

```
var div = $("#accordion").find("div:first").html();
arr=2;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++)
{
    $("#accordion").append(div);
}

console.log($("#accordion").find(".create")) //always print 1

$("#accordion").children(".create").each(function(index) {
    console.log("==") //prints only once
});
```

`EDIT`

arr.length is not the issue for me..when i print $("#accordion").html() i see two divs with .create but cannot count it or get it in the each loop

Comment: can you add your rendered html ?

Comment: what is the result of `console.log($("#accordion").children().length)`

Comment: Can you please add your html that is coming from $("#accordion").find("div:first").html()?

Comment: ($("#accordion") has many childrens

Comment: You need to post the contents of `#accordion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be that since you are using `.html()` to create `div`, it gets the inner contents of the first div, not the child itself.

You need to use clone() here

```
var div = $("#accordion").find("div:first");
arr=2;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    $("#accordion").append(div.clone());
}

console.log($("#accordion").find(".create")) //always print 1

$("#accordion").children(".create").each(function(index) {
    console.log("==") //prints only once
});
```

Comment: But after appending why is that i cannot see the second div?

Answer (score 1):

You never go into your loop because of `arr.length`. I believe you meant `i<arr-1`.

Comment: Then do  `for(var i=0;i<arr-1;i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
var div = $("#accordion").find("div:first").html();
arr=2;
for(var i=0;i<arr-1;i++)
{
    $("#accordion").append(div);
}

console.log($("#accordion").find(".create")) //always print 1

$("#accordion").children(".create").each(function(index) {
    console.log("==") //prints only once
});
```

It should work.
Actually arr has value 2 and you were using arr.length-1. It will always return 0.

Comment: yes i want the div to be appended only once so i use arr.length -1